# How to config Nutch to crawl only the URLs in seeklist? (no crawl back need)

Tags: solr, nutch

I have a url seedlist contains more than 100000 urls. I know that nutch will crawl not only the urls in the seedlist but also any url links found inside the websites. However, I would like to know is there any way to stop this behavior ? So that only the urls specified in the seedlist are needed to be crawled.

Answer (score 3):

In your nutch-site.xml configuration , set the "db.ignore.external.links" property to true.

This will ignore any urls to domains outside the injected list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [crawl command](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3.1_Using_the_Crawl_Command) check for the depth parameter.

> -depth depth indicates the link depth from the root page that should be crawled.

Using this you can control what level of depth you need Nutch to crawl. Having a value of 1 probably would limit it to the base page only.